# How to implement pagination with react and node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am building a blog using react.js, node and mongodb. The user creates a post that get's pushed to the database and I display all posts on the homepage, I want to make pagination available, so that only 5 posts are allowed on the homepage if there are more than five than a paginated page should appear showing the next five and etc, is there a suitable library that can do that?

Comment: I suggest you think twice before downvoting, the question is right on point, helpful and adequate. I have searched in Google and I am just not sure which one to use when there are tousands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)? You can use pagination in queries to MongoDB, something like `{ skip: page * 5, limit: 5 }` for Mongoose. Property `page` should be defined in your requests from frontend.